# Why is Predicate<? super SomeClass> not applicable to Object?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, predicate

Assume we have a predicate declared as `Predicate<? super SomeClass>`. I would naively expect it to be applicable to any superclass of `SomeClass` up the hierarchy, including `Object`.

However this predicate is not applicable to `Object`. I get the following error:

> The method test(capture#3-of ? super SomeClass) in the type Predicate is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

[Demo](https://ideone.com/pTxzvl).

Why is `Predicate<? super SomeClass>` not applicable to an instance of `Object`?

The code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.function.Predicate;


/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Predicate<? super URL> p = u -> u.getFile().isEmpty();
        p.test(new Object());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to use super? Looking at the code in the demo it seems as if you want "? extends SomeClass"?

Comment: @ewramner This is not practical/real code. I'm simply trying to understand how `<? super T>` works.

Comment: @ewramner *I think you should be able to use `Object`* - I have demonstrated that this is not the case.

Comment: fyi take a look at: [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397) , it's a pretty good rule of thumb to keep.

Comment: What you want in your code is a variable of type `Predicate<Object>`, a `Predicate<? super X>` behaves by design like `Predicate<X>` but allows more flexibility when chosing a concrete implementation (There is no `= new Predicate<? super X>()`, you have to specify a concrete type). You can for example take an implementation that is `Predicate<Object>`, because that code also works fine on X. It's not about allowing any T in the `test` method.

Comment: The only difference between a variable (or function parameter) of type `Predicate<? super X>` and one of type `Predicate<X>` is the acceptable conversions when binding an object. When you *have one*, you can only *use* the members of  `Predicate<X>`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For a `Predicate<? super SomeClass>` variable, you can assign a `Predicate<SomeClass>` instance, or a `Predicate<Object>` instance.

However, you can't pass an `Object` to the `test()` method of a `Predicate<SomeClass>`. You can only pass a `SomeClass` instance.

Therefore you can't pass an `Object` to the `test()` method of a `Predicate<? super SomeClass>`

Consider the following:

```
Predicate<URL> p1 = u -> u.getFile().isEmpty();
Predicate<? super URL> p2 = p1;
```

`p2` is referring to a `Predicate<URL>`, so you can't pass a `new Object()` to its `test()` method.

In other words, in order for `p.test(new Object())` to be accepted by the compiler, it must be valid for **any** `Predicate` that can be assigned to the `Predicate<? super URL> p` variable. Since the `Predicate<URL>` `Predicate` can be assigned to that variable, and its `test()` method **cannot** accept an `Object`, `p.test(new Object())` cannot be accepted by the compiler.

BTW, in your specific example, you are creating a `Predicate<URL>`, and `URL` is a final class. Therefore, you should simply declare it as:

```
Predicate<URL> p = u -> u.getFile().isEmpty();
```

There's no reason for `? super` or `? extends`.

Comment: I understand that it *should not* work, but I don't understand why it does not work. I'm missing something fundamental here probably.

Comment: The code is not real/practical, I'm just trying to understand how `<? super T>` works.

Comment: `URL` is a final class is not a reason to remove `? super URL`,  this is true only for the case of `? extends URL`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the broader example:

```
Predicate<? super Integer> p;
```

In this situation, any of the following assignments is valid, right?

```
p = (Predicate<Integer>) i -> true; // but, only Integer can be applied
p = (Predicate<Number>)  n -> true; // Number and its sub-classes (Integer, Double...)
p = (Predicate<Object>)  o -> true; // any type
```

So, if in the end it is:

```
Predicate<? super Integer> p  = (Predicate<Integer>) i -> true;
```

Then, certainly, neither `Number` nor `Object` **could not** be applied to the predicate.

To guarantee type safety, a compiler allows only those types, which are valid for any of the possible assignments to the `Predicate<? super Integer>` - so, only `Integer` in this particular example.

Changing the lower bound from `Integer` to `Number` extends the boundaries respectively:

```
Predicate<? super Number> p  = (Predicate<Number>) n -> true;
```

Now, the predicate can be applied to the `Number` and any of its sub-classes : `Integer`, `Double` etc.

### Summarizing

The only types which can be applied to the `Predicate<? super SomeClass>` without breaking a type safety guarantees: the lower bound itself and its sub-classes.

Answer (score 1):

The Predicate *already has* a type. The type the predicate accepts can't be decided at the point when you try and call it. It has a type, and that type is some superclass of X; it's just unknown.

If I have a `Predicate<Collection>`, that could be referenced as a `Predicate<? super List>`. But that doesn't mean that it will accept any `Object`. The `? extends X` generic type doesn't mean it will accept *anything* matching the given constraints. It means it is a predicate for some kind of unknown type that matches the given constraints.

```
Predicate<? super List> predicate = Collection::isEmpty;
predicate.test(new Object()); // Should this be valid? Clearly not
```

Comment: *"It means it is a predicate for some kind of type matching the given constraints."* - but `Object` is a type which matches given constraints.

Comment: But a `Predicate<? super X>` isn't a predicate for _any type_ matching the given constraints. It is a predicate for _some unknown type_ matching the given constraints.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. Can't `Object` be this "unknown type"?

Comment: @lexicore Object means anthing. ;-)

Comment: @lexicore The `Predicate` already _has_ a type. The type the predicate accepts can't be decided at the point when you try and call it. It has a type, and that type is some superclass of `X`; it's just unknown.

Comment: @khelwood If the problem is that the type is unknown, why does it accept an instance of `URL` then?

Comment: Because the type is unknown but _must_ be a superclass of URL. That's what `super URL` is for. Therefore it can be passed a URL.

Comment: We're running in circles, sorry. *"Because the type is unknown but must be a superclass of URL. ... Therefore it can be passed a URL."* - `Object` satisfies this condition, why can't it be passen an instance of `Object`?

Comment: @khelwood Does it means '? super X exclude Object'

Comment: The object you pass into the predicate must be a subtype of the actual type of the predicate, because that's how subtyping works. The actual type of the predicate is _some unknown superclass of URL_. Therefore a URL is an acceptable parameter. And an Object is not, because there is no guarantee that the predicate's type is compatible with Object.

Answer (score 1):

The java tutorial pages provides some good information about [upper](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) / [lower](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) bounded wildcards when using generics.

It also provides some [guidelines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) for using wildcards which can help decide which wildcard you should use:

> An "In" Variable
>       An "in" variable serves up data to the code. Imagine a copy method with two arguments: copy(src, dest). The src argument provides the
>   data to be copied, so it is the "in" parameter. An "Out" Variable
>       An "out" variable holds data for use elsewhere. In the copy example, copy(src, dest), the dest argument accepts data, so it is the
>   "out" parameter.
>
> Of course, some variables are used both for "in" and "out" purposes —
>   this scenario is also addressed in the guidelines.
>
> You can use the "in" and "out" principle when deciding whether to use
>   a wildcard and what type of wildcard is appropriate. The following
>   list provides the guidelines to follow: Wildcard Guidelines:
>
> ```
> An "in" variable is defined with an upper bounded wildcard, using the extends keyword.
> An "out" variable is defined with a lower bounded wildcard, using the super keyword.
> In the case where the "in" variable can be accessed using methods defined in the Object class, use an unbounded wildcard.
> In the case where the code needs to access the variable as both an "in" and an "out" variable, do not use a wildcard.
> ```
>
> These guidelines do not apply to a method's return type. Using a
>   wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces
>   programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a complex subject. These `? extends T` and `? super T` declarations are rather supposed to create a "matching" between classes.

If a class defines a method taking a `Consumer`, say something like `Iterable<T>.foreach()`, it defines this consumer to accept everything which can take a `T`. Thus, it [defines it as `forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-). Why? Because an `Iterator<Integer>`'s `foreach()` can be called with a `Consumer<Number>` or even a `Consumer<Object>`. This is something which wouldn't be possible without the `? super T`.

OTOH, if a class defines a method taking a `Supplier`, say something like `addFrom`, it defines this supplier to supply everything which is a `T`. Thus, it defines it as `addFrom(Supplier<? extends T> supplier)`. Why? Because a `ThisClass<Number>`'s `addFrom()` can be called with a `Supplier<Integer>` or a `Supplier<Double>`. This is something which wouldn't be possible without the `? extends T`.

Maybe a better example for the latter: [`List<E>.addAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) which takes a `Collection<? extends E>`. This makes it possible to add the elements of a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Number>`, but not vice versa.