# The method add(? extends Customer) in the type List<? extends Customer> is not applicable for the arguments (Customer)

Tags: java, generics, collections

When using `List<? extends Customer>`, the add() method gives error while adding Customer object as well as LocalCustomer(Sub class of Customer) object. But when I typecast the reference variable of `List<? extends Customer>` to `List<Customer>`, it works fine. Why?

```
public class GenericInheritance {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<? extends Customer> custs2=new ArrayList<LocalCustomer>();
    custs2.add(new Customer());                                 // Error
    custs2.add(new LocalCustomer("ABC"));                       // Error
    ((List<Customer>)custs2).add(new LocalCustomer("PQR"));     // No Error
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292109/explanation-of-the-get-put-principle

Comment: `List<? extends Customer>` means "a list of some unnamed/unknown type which extends `Customer`", not "a list of any type which extends `Customer`".

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248764/why-is-predicate-super-someclass-not-applicable-to-object